# "Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader"

Tags: python, python3, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I've been trying to use OpenCV and following [this tutorial](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/) where they decided to use virtualenvs but this isn't working out for me, and other similar questions aren't helping. Using 16.04 LTS

I installed it and it gave me a few errors regarding virtualenv, I thought it was normal and followed with the tutorial, but apparently when trying to use "workon cv" it gives me errors as well so it isn't something normal.

When I open the terminal this appears:

```
    /home/user/anaconda3/bin/python: Error while finding spec for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (ImportError: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.
```

I have no idea of what I'm supposed to do with this.

When using "workon cv" this errors appear:

```
    /home/user/anaconda3/bin/python: Error while finding spec for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (ImportError: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')
/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python: Error while finding spec for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (ImportError: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')
```

What am I supposed to do? I've used a virtual environment tool before I think, (venv if not mistaken).

Thanks a ton, I hope this hasn't been answered before, but all I found didn't really help me.

Answer (score 1):

I run...

```
conda install -c eumetsat virtualenvwrapper
```

and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

in my case had to upgrade stevedore
I had installed bandit and precommit and had to update a few things in relation to that. Stevedore was the last thing i had to upgrade
pip3 install -U stevedore

Here is part of the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/stevedore/_cache.py", line 159, in _get_data_for_path
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/.cache/python-entrypoints/d4b9.........
```

Comment: I would suggest you say what version of Ubuntu you are using so any future user will know that the path 3.7 may need to be updated.